# How to know if QProcess is asking for input?

Tags: qt, qprocess

I'm trying to build a GUI wrapper over an external command line application. Everything is fine until this application wants to get an input from user. **How to know if the process is asking for an input?** For example, so I could show the GUI input dialog for the end user.

Also, the fact is I don't need this input functionality at all, so it would also be fine to simply omit / suppress the input.

Comment: Take a look at: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setInputChannelMode and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#ProcessChannelMode-enum. I think you can forward the input to the main process and then do something with it. You have to figure it out for your scenario.

Comment: How would the user normally know if the command line application required input?  Does it not prompt?

Comment: @G.M. It does. I mean I probably need some sort of signal when the QProcess asks for input, so my GUI application could handle this input request.

Comment: So, when the command line app prompts that should result in a [`readyReadStandardOutput`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readyReadStandardOutput) signal being emitted from the `QProcess`.  Your GUI app needs to react to that.  This could be awkward, though, due to buffering of the command line apps stdout.

Comment: @G.M. `readyReadStandardOutput` is emitted when *any* output is avaiable, not only the pre-input prompt. Are you suggesting to (for example) check if the output string is equal to "Enter your name" or something like that and then react to the input?

Comment: Exactly.  It's up to you to read/interpret the output from the command line app.

Comment: @G.M. The underlying console application is localized in many languages, so this is where the described method gets very tricky. Anyway, seems this is the only way for now. Thanks a lot!